# Поиск одинаковых символов идущих подряд (от 2 до 9)

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Всем привет!
Написал функцию, которая проверяет наличие одинаковых цифр идущих подряд, и показывает количество таких блоков.
Выдаёт список с циферками которые показывают сколько блоков есть и по сколько повторений в каждом.
Но меня не оставляют мысли, что можно было сделать это аккуратнее и компактнее.

Подскажите есть какие то библиотеки, функции, регулярки для подобного рода задач?

```
def check_repeat_digits(55533):
    a = 0
    score = 0
    score_mass = []
    sid = str(id)
    for i in sid:
        try:
            # проверка среза есть ли в нём дубликаты and предотвращаем выход за границы
            if len(set(sid[a:a+2])) == 1 and a < len(sid)-1: если ОК то 
                score += 1
            # если блок одинаковых цифр прервался, заносим инфу в список, и обнуляемся
            elif score > 0:
                # +1 что бы корректно отображалось кол-во символов в блоке
                score_mass.append(score+1)
                score = 0
            else:
                a += 1
                continue
        except:
            exit()
        a += 1
    print(score_mass)

>>> [3, 2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте регулярку

```
import re

res = re.findall(r"((\d)\2{1,})", "5551888337771234555")

print(res)
```

если вам надо искать не 2 и больше, а N и больше символов, то укажите кол-во символов в `{1,}`

> (от 2 до 9)

будет означать `{1,8}`

т.е. ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
import re

def check_repeat_digits(value):
    return [len(obj[0]) for obj in re.findall(r"((\d)\2{1,8})", str(value))]
```

Comment: Zhihar, спасибо огромное! Я даже немножечко обалдел как можно уместить всё в одну строку :D
Осталось разобраться как работает эта строка. Т.к. с регулярками не знаком совсем. Только сегодня узнал что такое есть. И с генераторами еще пока на "вы" :)

Comment: `\d` - цифра,  `(...)` - группа, которая ищется (в данном случае нужна, чтобы можно было получить доступ к результату поиска, `\1` - результат поиска первой группы, `\2` - результат поиска второй группы и т.д., `{x, y}` - кол-во повторений от x до y, таким образом мы ищем цифру `\d`, после которой идет та же самая цифра `\2`, которая повторяется от 1 до 8 раз `{1,8}`. мы ищем вторую группу, потому что весь наш поисковый запрос завернут в первую группу, это я сделал потому что просто `(\d)\1{1,8}` нашло бы только первое появление нескольких символов, а нам нужны все появления

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение!

Answer (score 0):

Вам возможно понравится класс `Counter` из стандартной библиотеки `collection`.
 Более подробно с этим и другими полезными классами вы можете ознакомится по [ссылке](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).
Прикрепляю альтернативу вашей функции с использованием данного класса. Если что непонятно - пишите, прокомментирую. Единственное отличие что моя реализация выходит за ограничения с поиском одинаковых цифр от 2 до 9, но мне кажется, что рассмотрев более общий вариант куда легче написать частный с дополнительным условием.

```py
def check_repeat_digits(number):
    print([val for key, val in Counter([int(i) for i in str(number)]).items()])
```

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ. "Counter" полезная штука что бы считать все встречающиеся дубликаты, но проблема что он суммирует их в один. Т.е. при ```number = 55533555``` функция вернёт -> [6, 1].
А мне нужно что бы возвращала -> [3, 2, 3].
Но, энивей спасибо за ответ. Он мне тоже пригодился

Answer (score 0):

Для общей задачи группировки есть библиотечная функция. Ну для Вашей задачи можно еще отфильтровать группы с длиной 1

```
import itertools
print([(len(list(g[1])), g[0]) for g in itertools.groupby('5551888337771234555')])
```